# Changing innerHTML of script tags in IE for loading google plusone button explicitly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-plus-one

To add Google's plusone button on your website the following script tag is to be inserted (for explicit load).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {"parsetags": "explicit"}
</script>
```

It looks pretty straight forward in HTML. However I wan't to insert the script using a JS file. So I use the following code:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
e.id = "googplusonescript";
e.innerHTML = '{"parsetags": "explicit"}';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
```

It works pretty awesome in all the browsers except IE because IE doesn't allow us to write the innerHTML of script tags. Anywork arounds anyone ? (I have jquery inserted in the page. So can use jquery too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came across the same issue.
Under IE you should use 
script.**text** = '{"parsetags": "explicit"}';
instead of script.innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

try creating a textNode and appending it to your script tags:

```
var myText = document.createTextNode('{"parsetags": "explicit"}'); 
myScriptTag.appendChild(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
window['___gcfg'] = { parsetags: 'explicit' };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var ispoloaded;

function showpo() {
var pohd = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var poscr = document.createElement('script');
poscr.type ='text/javascript';
poscr.async = true;
poscr.text ='{"parsetags": "explicit"}'; //works on IE too
poscr.src = "http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
pohd.appendChild(poscr);


ispoloaded = setInterval(function () {


//check if plusone.js is loaded
if(typeof gapi == 'object') {
//break the checking interval if loaded
clearInterval(ispoloaded);
//render the button, if passed id does not exists it renders all plus one buttons on page
gapi.plusone.go("idthatexists");
}

}, 100); //checks every 0.1 second



}
```